# Can Chlorhexidine Gluconate (CHG) be used for disinfection of medical device (e.g. of polyethylene material)?

Tags: aqueous-solution, polymers, cleaning

Chlorhexidine is commonly used as a skin antiseptic, hand disinfectant, endodontic irrigant etc. It possess antibacterial and antifungal properties, and is considered low toxicity when used in low concentration.

Some articles mentioned that Chlorhexidine is also used in disinfection of medical device/ surfaces in their description.
However, most commercial solutions are formulated for skin disinfection, and there are almost none of the studies that evaluates the antimicrobial effect of Chlorhexidine on medical device/instrument.

Is Chlorhexidine suitable to be used as disinfectant for medical instruments (non-invasive) or hard surfaces? Since the antimicrobial effect is comparable to another common agent, povidone-iodine.